# I want to change the view of a spinner in android

Tags: android, android-studio, drop-down-menu, spinner

The spinner I made looks like this ([Spinner I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rFgP.png)).

I want it to look like this or at least not cover the spinner itself ([Spinner i desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaCVR.png)).

This is my xml for the spinner:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />
```

And this is my java code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.change_type);
    String[] spinnerArray=new String[]{"Binary","Length"};
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArray);
    spinner= (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.change_type).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.setDropDownWidth(this.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

what should I do ?

Comment: `at least not cover the spinner itself` what do you mean by this?

Comment: i want a spinner like the second picture. the popup menu is shifted downward so that it doesn't cover the spinner.